# Another extending program with the "this" keyword included

Tags: java

I was making my second program and decided to try to make a program that stores values, then allows them to be called in other methods or in my program, other classes. Then I tried to add all these values with the this.arguement syntax to no success.

All of the this.args are producing the same error, "Error: cannot find symbol" line 39.

What there is wrong?

```
class students
{
    public void students()
    {
        String strgirl = "Jenna";
        String strboy = "Tommy";
    }
}

class math extends students
{
    public void studentsmath()
    {
        double tommymath = 88.49;
        double jennamath = 91.15;
    }
}

class english extends math
{
    public void studentsenglish()
    {
        double tommyenglish = 91.5;
        double jennaenglish = 89.18;
    }
}

class science extends english
{
    public void studentsscience()
    {
        double tommyscience = 70.11;
        double jennascience = 96.1;
    }
}

class averagetotal extends science
{
    public void averagetotal()
    {
        double total;
        this.tommymath + this.jennamath + this.tommyenglish + this.jennaenglish + this.tommyscience + this.jennascience = total;
        System.out.println(total);
        double average;
        average = (total / 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variables are not class fields. Look up "scope".

Comment: For 'this' keyword, pls ref to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is that all the variables you are trying to reference by `this` are local variables. See http://www.coderanch.com/t/416862/java/java/Difference-Variable-Field.

What you need to do is put the declarations in the main class body and out of the method body.

i.e., instead of

```
class students {
public void students()
{
    String strgirl = "Jenna";
    String strboy = "Tommy";
}
```

}

use

```
class students{
    String strgirl = "Jenna";
    String strboy = "Tommy";
}
```

Comment: Alright but, maybe I was taught wrongly but I thought Classes could NOT have straight up code in them? I thought it was Class/method/THEN code.

Comment: @Dont `String strgirl = "Jenna";` is not really "code".  It's a variable declaration with an initializer.  If you said `String strgirl; strgirl = "Jenna";` the second statement would be an assignment statement, which _would_ be code that can't appear directly in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable `tommyscience` in the function `studentsscience()` in class `science`. `tommyscience` only exists when `studentsscience()` is called, and stops existing when that function is complete. `tommyscience`'s [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) is local only to that function.

Therefore, attempting to use it in the `averagetotal` class cannot work, because the variable, *as far as the `averagetotal()` constructor is concerned* `tommyscience` does not exist. This is the same problem as with `jennaenglish`, `jennamath`, `jennascience`, `tommyenglish`, and `tommymath`;

That's why you're getting the `symbol not found` compiler errors.

Also:

- You should really consider capitalizing class names
- The `void` before the `averagetotal()` constructor (and in all classes) needs to be eliminated. It's legal, but it's not what you want. When you do this, all constructors will be executed in turn (instantiating a `new averagetotal()` will execute the constructors in this order: `averagetotal` -> `science` -> `english` -> `math` -> `students`), but until you fix your variable scoping problem, you'll still not have access to any of the variables as you want.
- Your classes have no state. There's no variable except inside functions. For example, instead of putting `String strgirl = "Jenna";` in a function, put it outside of the function, right at the top of the class (between the `public class` line and the `students` constructor).

There are some more fundamental problems, but these smaller ones should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you can declare the member fields with initializers.  It's probably more common to initialize them in constructors, though:

```
class math extends students
{ 
    public double tommymath;
    public double jennamath;

    public math()
    {
        tommymath = 88.49;
        jennamath = 91.15;
    }
}
```

`math()` is a constructor because it has the same name as the class.  When you say `new math()`, it executes the statements in the constructor.  The key is that you do **not** put the word `double` or any other type name before `tommymath` and `jennamath` in the constructor.  If you did, it would be a *new* local variable with the same name, and you wouldn't be initializing the field member.

One more thing: The way you wrote it, you wrote a method instead of a constructor:

```
class math extends students
{ 
    public double tommymath;
    public double jennamath;

    public void studentsmath()
    {
        tommymath = 88.49;
        jennamath = 91.15;
    }
}
```

This is perfectly legal, but now you actually have to *call* the `studentsmath` method in order to get the variables `tommymath` and `jennamath` initialized.  And I didn't see anywhere in your code where `studentsmath();` was called.  So you probably would have ended up with 0, instead of 88.49 or 91.15.